# Event sourcing : how to convert an aggregateRoot into another one

Tags: php, cqrs, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

Basically, the question is :

> how to correctly build an event storage for an event sourced system that should be able to :
>
> - convert an aggregate into another one,
> - keep the same Id,
> - and still be able to reconstitute it from the event stream?

**Now my example:**

i have a `ProspectiveCustomer` that can be converted to `PayingCustomer` like this :

`ProspectiveCustomer::convertToPayingCustomer(ProspectiveCustomerId $id)`

The PayingCustomer would keep the same Id so its lifetime can be followed up.

So now **imagine the following event Stream** :

1. *ProspectiveCustomer was added* to the CRM
2. *ProspectiveCustomer was made an offer*
3. *ProspectiveCustomer* accepted the offer and therefore *was converted to PayingCustomer*
4. *PayingCustomer paid its bill*

**Let's focus on point 4) :**

We'll have a commandHandler that recieves a paymentCommand {customerId:"123", amount:"500€"}.
Its job would be to :

1. reconstitute PayingCustomer from its events'history
2. call PayingCustomer::pay(Money $amount)

My question is about 1) reconstituting from History :

**The EventStorage service would :**

1. look up for the AggregateId
2. loads the events (SELECT * FROM Events WHERE ID = 'xxx')

The events'stack would now contain :

- ProspectiveCustomerWasAdded
- ProspectiveCustomerWasMadeAnOffer
- ProspectiveCustomerAcceptedTheOffer

How could the commandHandler process `PayingCustomer::reconstituteFromHistory(EventsHistory $events)` while the $events are events issued from / applyable to the `ProspectiveCustomer`

### **EDIT**

currently i'm handling the problem with PayingCustomer having its own Id, but holding a reference to the ProspectiveCustomerId.

But considering that :

1. this is the **same bounded context**,
2. the very **same customer's lifecycle (ProspectiveCustomer ends when PayingCustomer starts)**,

it kind of feels messy because the model is now polluted by 2 Ids whereas one should be enough.

**If it wouldn't be an event-sourced system, I'd definitly go for one unique Id.**

That being said, and considering **Event-sourcing is just an implementation** detail, i'm looking for a way to have both aggregates keeping the same Id.

Comment: of course you'd have a `ProspectiveCustomerConvertedToPayingCustomer` Event. And it would be no problem to apply it to PropsectiveCustomer, returning the PayingCustomer

Comment: but the problem is the reconstitution from the eventstream once it's been converted

Comment: I think of 'Paying Customer' and 'Prospective Customer' as 'states' not an entity. That is where I am misunderstanding. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thx for your concern. A prospectiveCustomer may have totally different invariants than the PayingCustomer, hence the need to explode the big CustomerAggreagte into 2 smaller but preciser ARs

Comment: You do not convert, you create a new aggregate. When you create an aggregate, you use an external id anyway, which is supplied to you within the event. You copy all the prospective customer aggregate details that you need to have in the paying customer aggregate. In two words - no aggregate conversion, just normal business flow.

Comment: >> no aggregate conversion, just normal business flow. --> YES YES i know! i wrote `ProspectiveCustomer::convertToPayingCustomer(ProspectiveCustomerId $id)` which emits a PropsectiveCustomerConvertedToPayingCustomer($customerId) event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two aggregates but there is no "conversion". You step on a dangerous road, which can lead you to converting shopping carts to orders (for example).

You already have two *different* concepts - prospective customer and paying customer. They were probably identified during your conversations with domain experts. This clearly means two aggregates, sometimes two bounded contexts. You should not do any conversion, but you can definitely create new aggregate reacting on something that happens in your system (order accepted).

1. Prospective customer created
2. Offer accepted
3. Paying customer created from prospective customer
4. Prospective customer removed (or marked as "converted", or deactivated)

I would also expect that the term "conversion" came to you from domain experts. This is normal, since in Sales they use this terminology to indicate that someone who was interested actually made a purchase. They indeed call it "conversion" and you would be right including it to your ubiquitous language by using "3. Prospective customer *converted*" but this has nothing to do with *technical* conversion, meaning changing the object type.

You need domain event handlers that would do (3) and (4) since you're saying this is the same bounded context.

Aggregate unique identity generation is not a function of the aggregate itself, it is done outside and the aggregates gets its identity when being created as a factory method or/and constructor parameter. Therefore, when you create paying customer from a prospective customer, nothing stops you from using the same identity.

However, you start to have assumptions that you always expect to have a prospective customer in order to retrieve your history or something else, using the same identity. Since this assumption is implicit, it is easily forgotten and in general especially discouraged in DDD (remember making implicit things explicit). You can easily keep the id reference to the prospective customer in your new paying customer and then you will be perfectly fine.

Comment: >>  you start to have assumptions that you always expect to have a prospective customer in order to retrieve your history or something else, ||| no i don't

Comment: >>You can easily keep the id reference to the prospective customer in your new paying customer || that's what i am currently doing, as stated in my Edit. But it feels messy (see edit). Again if I hadnt the issue of my events' stack containing events of two different Aggregate, i would keep the Id. This brings us back to my 3 last comments on the above answer

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I would strongly suggest using identity reference to ProspectiveCustomer from PayingCustomer without making any assumptions.

Comment: This is what i'm currently doing (see EDIT) but only because i'm using event sourcing. If i had a regular state persistent system, i would keep the same ID. Why should my storage define my modelling?

Comment: Well, I answered already. I am not sure you insist on your idea of reusing the id. You are trying to make things that are currently explicit, implicit. And this is *not* an improvement. I have not mentioned event sourcing in my answer, I would do it in any case, no matter how I persist my aggregates.

Comment: when i say keep the same Id, i mean something like `new PayingCustomer(new PayingCustomerId($prospectiveCustomerId->toString())`

Comment: You are trying to make things that are currently explicit, implicit. >> that's probably where I indeed get confused. Why is it more explicit to have [different Ids + holding reference] than one Id considering its one lifecycle in the same bounded context....

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that it is the same aggregate but with different states. But, as stated in the comments to the question, you need them to be two different aggregates.

When you convert your aggregate what you really do is creating a new aggregate, so I would solve this with a domain event handler. A domain event handler will react on events and issue commands, so let your `ProspectiveCustomer` dispatch something like a `OfferAcceptedEvent` that the event handler can act on.

This could be the process flow:

1. User accepts an offer and `ProspectiveCustomer` dispatches `OfferAcceptedEvent`.
2. The event handler reacts on `OfferAcceptedEvent` and dispatches a `CreatePayingCustomerCommand`. (The `OfferAcceptedEvent` should contain all the data it needs from `ProspectiveCustomer` to create the command)
3. The `PayingCustomer` is created

It is probably a good idea to include the `ProspectiveCustomerId` in the `PayingCustomerCreatedEvent` so that you can track the `PayingCustomer` back to the `ProspectiveCustomer`.

Comment: so in short, you wouldnt keep the same Id but have PayingCustomer holding a reference to ProspectiveCustomerId. Do i get you right?

Comment: Yes, the original ID belongs to the ProspectiveCustomer. The PayingCustomer should have its own ID.

Comment: that's what i' am currently doing but it feels messy. Considering this is the same bounded context, and this is the very same peron, it feels like it should keep the same Id because they each certainly have their own lifecycle, but one ends when the other starts.

Comment: Saga coordinates sequential actions and process managers execute long-running processes. You need no saga to subscribe to one domain event and issue a command. Regular domain event handler would do.

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie what is exactly the issue with keeping the id? Your aggregate constructor gets the id as the constructor parameter. If not, you should consider changing it. Issuing and assigning aggregate ids should not be done inside aggregates itself.

Comment: my issue with keeping the id is the aggregate's reconstitution from the events' stack as described in the **let's focus on point 4)** paragraph.

Comment: in short, when it comes to handle the paymentCommand{$customerId, $amount}, the handler would need to reconstitute the PayingCustomer. To do so, it will load the events' stack for the Id (with a DB query like SELECT * where ID = 'xxx'). And if the same Id is kept, the events' stack would contain events from the ProspectiveCustomer.

Comment: as mentionned in my EDIT, i know there's something wrong in my understanding because if it wouldnt be an ES system, i would definitly keep the same Id. And as ES should only be an implementation detail, that probably mean my event storage implementation is missing something.

Comment: @Developpeurtunisie try to avoid reusing the same ID for different aggregates. If they are different objects in your domain then they should have different ID:s.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev What would you say is the difference between a saga and a domain event handler that issues commands in a CQRS/ES system? Besides the fact that a saga can hold state (if needed) I do not see the difference.

Comment: There is a good overview of workflow, state machine, saga and process manager here http://kellabyte.com/2012/05/30/clarifying-the-saga-pattern/. Saga is a different thing, it is executing commands in certain order and provide compensating actions to roll back the whole sequence if needed. Domain event handler does nothing like this, I am not sure why apply complex pattern on a simple thing.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev - Given that a saga is designed to handle failing actions, a saga is not suitable to solve this problem. I changed my answer accordingly. Thanks.